# How do I grep and sort using this specific pattern?

Tags: linux, grep

I want to get the numbers after the B*, but not including *Y* and after it. I tried to use this command which I got from a friend, but it doesn't work:

```
grep -oP 'B.\K[\w\s\d]' < tus.txt | sort -u
```

#### tus.txt

```
~TUS*21424565*4716129*B*222791885833*Y*
~TUS*21470045*4733746*B*36*Y*19-OCT-16**B*2239681
~TUS*21758806*4932668*B*00081907*Y*2707826
~TUS*21758851*4932694*B*00082025*Y*2707871
~TUS*21758862*4932739*B*262105589241-20172-31489016
~TUS*21758767*4932626*B*00081684*Y*2707792
~TUS*21758861*4932693*B*00082024*Y*2707881
~TUS*21758895*4932764*B*4578873831221*Y*
~TUS*21760350*4933404*B*00082603*Y*2708838
~TUS*21759295*4932379*B*00082403*Y*2708332
```

#### Desired result:

```
222791885833
36
00081907
00082025
262105589241-20172-31489016
00081684
00082024
4578873831221
00082603
00082403
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command also works, you need to add a `*` or `+` to it:

```
$ grep -oP 'B.\K[\w\s\d]+' tus.txt | sort -u
00081684
00081907
00082024
00082025
00082403
00082603
222791885833
2239681
262105589241
36
4578873831221
```

Or, more simply:

```
$ grep -oP 'B\*\K[^*]*' tus.txt | sort -u
00081684
00081907
00082024
00082025
00082403
00082603
222791885833
2239681
262105589241
36
4578873831221
```

Or, use `awk` to print the penultimate `*`-separated field:

```
$ awk  -F'[*]' '{print $5}' tus.txt | sort -u
00081684
00081907
00082024
00082025
00082403
00082603
222791885833
2239681
262105589241
36
4578873831221
```

Answer (score 10):

The input is `*`-delimited.  Get the fifth field:

```
$ cut -d '*' -f 5 tus.txt
222791885833
36
00081907
00082025
262105589241-20172-31489016
00081684
00082024
4578873831221
00082603
00082403
```

This is the desired output that you mentioned, but you also talk about sorting it:

```
$ cut -d '*' -f 5 tus.txt | sort -u
00081684
00081907
00082024
00082025
00082403
00082603
222791885833
262105589241-20172-31489016
36
4578873831221
```

If you, for whatever reason, want to sort the *original* data on this field (not removing duplicates here):

```
$ sort -t '*' -k5,5 tus.txt
~TUS*21758767*4932626*B*00081684*Y*2707792
~TUS*21758806*4932668*B*00081907*Y*2707826
~TUS*21758861*4932693*B*00082024*Y*2707881
~TUS*21758851*4932694*B*00082025*Y*2707871
~TUS*21759295*4932379*B*00082403*Y*2708332
~TUS*21760350*4933404*B*00082603*Y*2708838
~TUS*21424565*4716129*B*222791885833*Y*
~TUS*21758862*4932739*B*262105589241-20172-31489016
~TUS*21470045*4733746*B*36*Y*19-OCT-16**B*2239681
~TUS*21758895*4932764*B*4578873831221*Y*
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following approach:

```
grep -Po '(?<=\*B\*)[^*]+' tus.txt | sort -u
```

The output:

```
00081684
00081907
00082024
00082025
00082403
00082603
222791885833
2239681
262105589241-20172-31489016
36
4578873831221
```

---

Note, `sort -u` will reorder the initial `grep` output